# Historical test coverage data for a given class/method

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, trend, test-coverage

We are trying to pull historical test coverage data (more like weekly/mothly trend) for a given resource. At a project level we are able to fetch required data by using the API https://sonar-service/api/resources?resource=com.demo.project:demo-project&metrics=new_coverage&includetrends=true.

But the same is not working if we try to fetch information at a class level (https://sonar-service/api/resources?resource=com.demo.project:demo-project:src/main/java/com/demoClass.java&metrics=new_coverage&includetrends=true). It simply returns current value.

Is there any way to fetch historical coverage data for a given class/method (either by using APIs or querying Database).

If it is not possible in Sonarqube 5.x & below, do we have any simpler way in 6.x version of Sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

Historical data is not retained at the file level. I don't believe it ever has been.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Ann. Greatly appreciate it. Do you recommend anything for us to achieve this? We are looking for this to build an utility for management reporting at organization level and it is very important to have the trend at file level for this.